# Refer to Table Column by Name rather than Table Column Address

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 sheets.
Sheet 1 is a formatted as a table and is where the user pastes data in.
Sheet 2 takes part of that table data and prepares it for pivot table analysis.
The problem is that the input from the user is not always in the same order.
Meaning the order of the columns changes:

Example:

Today is the order

```
ID    Manager  Status
```

Tomorrow is the order

```
Manager Status ID
```

I want the user to paste in the data in the order it comes out and then have my sheet refer to the column called `ID|status|Manager` no matter where it is in the table.

If I use:
`=Table1[id]`
then the problem is that if the order changes then `Table1[id]` changes to 
`Table1[Manager]`, (as per the example).

The only solution I have found is: `=XLOOKUP("ID";'Sheet1'!$1:$1;'Sheet1'!2:2)`

Which looks for `ID` in `row 1` and then spits out the data in `row 2` for that column.

This can be dragged down to get the result for `row 3`, `row 4` etc. This gives the desired result.   However, it is very heavy to run for Excel (I do this over quite a large data range) + it is not dynamically resized.

This is why I wanted to use Table column references.

Does anyone have any bright ideas on how to solve this?

I use Excel 365

Comment: INDEX & MATCH works the same as XLOOKUP, and isn't heavy at all to run on Excel

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that was very straight forward.

```
=INDIRECT("Table1[id]";FALSE)
```

This way it will always search for the Column that is called ID no matter where it is in the table. The only problem is that you can drag that out across several columns but that wasn't an issue for me.